# regex for exactly one capital letter and one digit within a certain range

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to write javascript that validates a form value of a grid coordinate.

The grid has A to H and 1 to 8, with coordinates written as a letter followed by a number eg. "A1", "H8", "B6", "F3".

Can anyone give me a regex that will rule out anything other than coordinates within that range.

I tried the following:

```
/^[A-H][1-8]$/
```

based on my really limited knowledge of regex but that hasn't worked out

Comment: `but that hasn't worked out` - please edit the question to explain what you're expecting and what you're seeing (with related JS code/examples). That regex does what is described - matching strings that consist of only one letter, A to H, followed by a number, 1 to 8 - so if it "doesn't work" the problem isn't the regex itself.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you mean with "*hasn't worked out*", please? Your RegExp looks correct therefore it might be useful to know how it fails (no match at all, incorrect matches, etc.) and maybe see the code where it is used.

Comment: The regex say: looking for a line starting (`^`) with a capital letter in the range from "A" to "H" (`[A-H]`) followed by a digit in the range from "1" to "8" (`[1-8]`) and then the string must be end (`$`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexp looks correct, you may want to make it more robust in this way:
`/^\s*[A-H][1-8]\s*$/`

This should match things like "A6" or "B7" even with spaces at the beginning or at the end.

A very useful tool to test your regexps is this: https://regex101.com/

Comment: This works great, I needed something like this too, thanks

Comment: @RodolfoSccani: I think the `i`-flag makes it all case insensitive! But there must be a capital letter!

Comment: @AndyU. you are right, I've corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To be sure your string starts with "A"- "H" followed by "1" - "8" it's correct to say `^[A-H][1-8]` but then there may be some more content. So you can write a `.*` to allow some. To get this content, write it between `(` and `)` to build a group.

```txt
^[A-H][1-8](.*)$
```

If a line matches, you can get the content behind the range out of `$1`, the first group. Be sure, that your regex works case sensitive!

If you want to prevent matching lines with another range (like "B4 foo Bar bAz **D7** xxx" you need a lookaround:

```txt
^[A-H][1-8]((?:(?![A-H][1-6]).)*)$
```

[image: source: https://jex.im/regulex]